# Is it possible to use parametrized GWT Messages in UIBinder XML layout?

Tags: gwt, internationalization, message

I have some Messages, described in com.google.gwt.i18n.client.Messages interface implementation and binded with some resource files. I use Messages and not Constants because I want to be able to specify some dynamical parameters while getting the messages. I.e. my messages are defined as "some text {0} - is value of my param" and I use corresponding method call with one (int this case) parameter.

A question is: how can I use my parametrized messages in UIBinder XML layout?

Imagine I have a button and I want to set its label. The label depends on some parameter, for example button number. So I need a message which looks somehow like this: "my button No {0}". How can I specify this parameter in XML layout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't; you'll have to set the label from your Java code.

Comment: The GWT compiler will also throw "Could not find no-arg method named myParametrizedMessage in type com.example.MessageResources".